# how to combine xargs to locate commands

Tags: syntax, command, virtual, python-xarray, xargs

I am trying to experiment the using of xargs combined with locate command.

I would like to get the result sorted by oldest file to the newest.

I am not sure of the following syntax:

```
locate file1 | xargs ls -lrt
```

Another option I considered was `xargs -I{} ls -lrt {}`.

What is the utility of using the `-I{}` option with the brackets in `ls {}`?

Is there any way to produce my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the utility of using the -I{} option with the brackets in ls {}?

For xargs, the -I{} option allows you to substitute one of the entry lines with the "{}" in the xargs command line arguments.

This allows you to format the command in a number of ways. For example the simple case:

```
% printf one | xargs -I{} echo {}
one
```

Results in "one" being printed once. However you may also do it twice:

```
% printf one | xargs -I{} echo {} {}
one one
```

> Is there any way to produce my desired output?

You initial request can be accomplished in this way:

```
locate 199 | tr '\12' \0' | \
    xargs -0 stat -c "%Y %A %h %U %G %s %y %n" | \
    sort -n | \
    sed -e 's/^[0-9]* //'
```

Locate the files. For safety reasons assume lines are well formed and separated by returns. Convert those returns to nulls with `tr`. Run the `stat` command with the unix epoch timestamp at the start of the line, with the rest in `/bin/ls` format. Use `sort` to order them by oldest to newest. Finally remove the temporary epoch timestamp from the start.

I created two files, 1990 and 1999. Here is the sorted output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 1990-12-11 22:33:00.000000000 -0500 1990
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 2022-09-07 14:31:43.191251897 -0400 1999
```